# Adding non project folders to TFS with Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

I am using Team Foundation "Service" with Git SVC. All the code etc is pushed nicely but I would also like to push documentation folders, etc which sit beneath the solution directory but are not in the vs solution itself.

Im not terribly familiar with Git, is this something I need to do via the command line? If so would I have manually to push these each time via the command line or will they auto-sync after the first time?

Answer (score 0):

I reckon your documentation folder isn't being tracked (in simple it is being ignored). What you can do is, go at root folder of your repository you will find a file named .gitignore. Open it, and verify if you find path to your document folder there.

This is basically a file (owned by git) that explicitly tells it to not track changes in these folders/files.

Incase you see that document folder's path there, just remove it and save the file.